# Decide on route-basis what outlet to render into

Tags: javascript, ember.js, modal-dialog, ember-router

So I've got two different outlets in my Handlebars markup. One outlet is unnamed `{{outlet}}` and one is named `{{outlet modal}}` (I've implemented a modal like in the [Ember Cookbook](http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/)).

One requirement for the app I'm making is that things that show up in the modal should be linkable. For instance, the resource 'cars' should show up there. I can figure out how to make a link to `/cars/52` and have it render in that outlet, but how do I make a route rule like that?

**How can you say a route (like `/cars/:car_id`) render in a specific outlet?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful, when you start rendering to different outlets you need to be sure that the outlet is also being rendered (aka that it's a parent of the current route, such as application).

```
App.CarsRoute = App.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('cars', {   // the template to render
      into: 'application',          // the route to render into
      outlet: 'modal',              // the name of the outlet in the route's template
      controller: 'cars'        // the controller to use for the template
    });
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Comment: Thank you! I'll report back soon